# update wizard didn't show the column that i added in db

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, oop

update wizard didn't show the column that i added in database. Any solution for this? I was once with this prob before but everything go back after i restart the IDE.

Could not parse the configuration file. The error message is: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: projectItems'. Try editing the file manually and then saving it.

Comment: "please can you fix my car, it's not working" ...can you fix my car based on that alone? Or would you need to actually look at the car, do you think? Same with code...we can't fix what we can't see. Please provide some relevant information - code, config, full error messages and what is generating them, etc.

Comment: I was doing a tool in VS and it created a DataTable and a TableAdapter, neither one of them was updated when I updated the format of the SQL table or changed the number of parameters that the stored procedure took.  I thought something was "cached" and took me awhile to figure out what was happening.

Comment: @ADyson sry, thats all the info i got from this error, just the only message and i dont even know why at that time, even tho i've scanned some key words to see if there anything wrong

Comment: cool thank you guys, I've already fixed it while checking the code line by line, I have found some of the schema in my dataModel.edmx didn't change not sure if is my careless mistake forgot to build or just vs bugs. Everything is fine after i changed it manually to the current schema

Answer (score 0):

cool thank you guys, I've already fixed it while checking the code line by line, I have found some of the schema in my dataModel.edmx didn't change not sure if is my careless mistake forgot to build or just vs bugs. Everything is fine after i changed it manually to the current schema

maybe if any of you met this prob, can try to find all(ctrl + shift + f) and see if they any imcompatible db name or anything else